# Nested/looping ajax function either makes php fail, or succeeds and makes website ui freeze

Tags: php, ajax, loops, asynchronous, nested

I have a php site. Once the page has loaded, ajax is run, then on success of that ajax, it loops through an array and runs ajax for each item in the array.

When I do it as i normally would (without using '`async: false`', the website UI works as expected, but the backend PHP processing is a jumble and fails. However when I set asynch to false for AJAX, the UI freezes but the backend processing runs perfectly.

How can I get ajax to run by iterating through an array, but making sure it has completed before continuing the loop?

Here is my overly-simplified javascript/ajax structure:

```
//run once
$.ajax({ url: '/functions/myfile.php',
         data: { blahblahblah },
         type: 'post',
         success: function(data){
             var ajaxIDToConvert = [(array contents)];
             var arrayLength = ajaxIDToConvert.length;
             //loops
                 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                     var meh = ajaxIDToConvert[i];

                     $.ajax({ url : '/functions/myfile.php',
                              type : 'post',
                              async: false,
                              data : { blahblahblah},
                              success : function(convertdata) {
                                  var convertResponse = JSON.parse(convertdata);
                              },
                              error: function (err) {
                              }
                            });
                 }
         },
         error: function (err) {

                         }
});
```

Heres a sample of my PHP log output when not using 'async false', as you can see the php code fails:

> File to convert: 527 
> Converting started for 527: Sat 06:30:06pm
>
> File to convert: 523 
> Converting started for 523: Sat 06:30:06pm
>
> File to convert: 522 
> Converting started for 522: Sat 06:30:06pm
>
> File to convert: 524 
> Converting started for 524: Sat 06:30:06pm
>
> File to convert: 526 
> Converting started for 526: Sat 06:30:06pm
>
> File to convert: 525 
> Converting started for 525: Sat 06:30:06pm
>   
> Converting ended for 522: Sat 06:30:38pm 
> 522 Not Created 
> Converting
>   ended for 524: Sat 06:30:39pm 
> 524 Not Created
>
> File to convert: 528
>  Converting started for 528: Sat 06:30:39pm
>
> File to convert: 529
>  Converting started for 529: Sat 06:30:39pm
>   Converting ended for 525: Sat 06:30:40pm 
> 525 Not Created
>  Converting
>   ended for 523: Sat 06:30:42pm 
> 523 Not Created

and here is a sample of the PHP output when using 'asynch: false':
(It produces the desired result...but the web page freezes while this is running)

> File to convert: 522 
> Converting started for 522: Sat 06:33:03pm
>   Converting ended for 522: Sat 06:33:12pm 
> 522 Created Successfully
>
> File to convert: 523
>  Converting started for 523: Sat 06:33:13pm
>   Converting ended for 523: Sat 06:33:22pm
>  523 Created Successfully
>
> File to convert: 524
>  Converting started for 524: Sat 06:33:22pm
>   Converting ended for 524: Sat 06:33:32pm
>  524 Created Successfully
>
> File to convert: 525
>  Converting started for 525: Sat 06:33:32pm
>   Converting ended for 525: Sat 06:33:42pm 
> 525 Created Successfully
>
> File to convert: 526
>  Converting started for 526: Sat 06:33:42pm
>   Converting ended for 526: Sat 06:33:52pm
>  526 Created Successfully

I've also tried doing the following within the success brackets of the first ajax, but it results in the same php execution problems as the first php output above:

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $total_files; i++){ 
   /* $.ajax returns a promise*/      
   var request = $.ajax({
        /* your ajax config*/
   })

   promises.push( request);
}

$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function(){
   alert('All done')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var ajaxIDsToConvert = [1, 2, 3];
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var promise = deferred.promise();

$.each(ajaxIDsToConvert, function(index, id) {
    promise = promise.pipe(function () { 
      return $.ajax({
        // do required actions with `id` variable
      });
    });
});

deferred.resolve();
```